# Mover objeto com posição de outro elemento na tela com clientX

Tags: javascript, asp

Tenho o seguinte código que é funcional no IE7

```
function ScrollControl()
{
    var obj = window.event.srcElement;
    var evento = obj.componentFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY);
    window.div_cabecalho.scrollLeft = obj.scrollLeft;
}
```

O mesmo código lê o movimento de uma tabela no momento do scroll e movimenta o cabeçalho da tabela ao mesmo tempo.
O código não funciona em outros navegadores, tentei com combinações de pageX mas não consigo valores na hora do movimento

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbnjuhvs/)

Comment: O problema não tá no "obj", consigo o mesmo valor que o IE retorna nos outros navegadores, meu problema está com o "event.clientX,event.clientY". 
Com um alert o IE retorna a posição numérica, nos outros navegadores retorna indefinido.

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle com o problema para podermos testar?

Comment: Esse problema ocorre porque os browsers "normais" não usam `window.event` mas sim o `event` passado como argumento numa função. Se mostrar mais código posso ajudar a corrigir isso.

Comment: De uma olhada [nessa referência do evento `scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window.onscroll) de um browser "normal". E informe mais detalhes sobre seu problema, pois com as informação existentes é um pouco difícil poder ajudar.

Comment: Tenho uma div com uma tabela e com o atributo onscroll="ScrollControl() que em tese executaria a função ScrollControl e faria o cabeçalho da tabela se mover junto com o scroll da tabela.

Comment: Editei e postei o código no jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Corrigido utilizando jquery

```
$('#div_grid').on('scroll', function () {
 $('#div_cabecalho').scrollLeft($('#div_grid').scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: Uma melhor explicação de como resolveu o problema seria muito bom.